# How to bind to an html attribute when the innerhtml itself is already generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

To start off, this is my index.html:

```
<template>
    <div class="panel" innerHtml="${renderedPanel}"></div>
</template>
```

The innerHtml is generated once the page is rendered and can end up being something like this:

```
<div class="panel au-target" au-target-id="294">
   <div>
      <button class.bind="classList">this is a button</button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="image.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now let's say I have this code in my script:

```
public classList = 'btn btn-success';

setTimeout(x => {
   this.classList= 'btn btn-warning';
},5000);
```

I'd expect the button to change after 5 seconds, but it won't. And in fact it won't even have any style to it because it doesn't seem to be able to bind to classList from the beginning. Aurelia is only binding to the initial HTML and not the one generated by the string I have that replaces innerHtml like so:

```
this.renderedPainel = this.renderedPainel.replace('$' + i + '$', '<button class.bind="test">Ok</button>');
```

Extra clarification: The timeout will happen only if I'm dealing with a slideshow and I will go through each image replacing the image in the html, so instead of replacing 'class' I actually need to replace the 'src' of the image without refreshing all of the other html because I have videos that need to continue playing. The $i$ is simply the index of the widget I am replacing.

Any clues on how to go about this?

Comment: A few questions:  How often is innerHTML being updated?  What's doing the updating?  What is `this` in your code?

Comment: @SephReed innerHTML (renderedPanel) is updated every time i change to a different panel (that has multiple widgets including images, videos, slideshows...). The updating is done by a method that loops through each widget in the panel and inserts the html into renderedPanel accordingly. `this` in my code is just a formatting bug, inside the button is just text.

Comment: I believe @SephReed was asking what the `this` in `this.classList= 'btn btn-warning';` refers to (as arrow functions have a lexically-bound `this`). Is your `setTimeout` in the same class as `public classList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what the problem was, but in another post: [Aurelia not binding innerHTML bind statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399496/aurelia-not-binding-innerhtml-bind-statements)

And this is more or less how I solved it: https://github.com/aurelia-contrib/aurelia-dynamic-html

I guess my question could have been better explained had I known better what I was dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you load your script on `window.load`, so that your script will be executed after all resource in the document has loaded.

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

```
window.onload = function() {

  public classList = 'btn btn-success';

  setTimeout(x => {
    this.classList= 'btn btn-warning';
  },5000);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

The only difference would be you have to change the `src` of the image on condition of slideshow, and instead of changing the class now you will have to change the `src` and it will load the new image when executed.

```
window.onload = function() {

  public classList = 'btn btn-success';

  //Assuming you have some logic to determine if you're in a slide show
  if(slideShow){
    setTimeout(x => {
      this.src = newSrc;
    },5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Right, I didn't include a lot of the code to simplify the problem at hand and replaced a lot of things. I'll clarify in an edit in my post. The reason I don't do that is because this function is not always invoked. The timeout will happen only if I'm dealing with a slideshow and I will go through each image replacing the image in the html, so instead of replacing 'class' I actually need to replace the 'src' of the image without refreshing all of the html because I have videos that need to continue playing.

Comment: window.onload is not even executed for me, weirdly. But either way I don't think that's the way to go as I already execute main code through the attached() lifecycle. A slideshow is ALSO a resource that is loaded at the same time as regular images and videos. After getting the widgets for that panel from the api, a method I have iterates through each widget in my panel and inserts them into the renderedPanel as html. Even if window.onload worked, how would it even know that the "load" is done after the iteration through each widget in panel list? Thanks though!